# ASP.NET trouble determining if user is logged in outside of code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method in a separate class that my code behind calls. Here is the method:

```
public static int InsertCondition(Condition condition)
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Accounts/Login.aspx", true);
            }
            try
            {
                var ConditionContext = new ConditionDataContext();
                ConditionContext.Conditions.InsertOnSubmit(condition);
                ConditionContext.SubmitChanges();
                int condition_id = condition.ID;
                return condition_id;
            }
            catch
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }

public static Guid GetCurrentUserGuid()
        {
            return (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        }
```

For some reason, I am not redirected while not logged in. Instead, the try block is executed and and I get a run-time error in the GetCurrentUserGuid function because the GetUser() object is not set to an instance. I understand this is because I am not logged in. That is what I am trying to prevent by checking if the user identity is authenticated. I just don't understand why I am not being redirected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the second code block fit in with the first? I don't see that referenced anywhere.

Comment: Can you you debug the application and put a breakpoint on InsertCondition and watch the expression `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`? Is it true or false?